# What does 便りの空だのみ mean?

Tags: meaning

お通｛おつう｝ is grieving for 又八｛またはち｝(武蔵｛たけぞう｝ is his friend) who left for war a year ago:

> その又八｛またはち｝は、村の武蔵｛たけぞう｝といっしょに、去年の夏、戦へとびだしてから、その年が暮れても、沙汰がなかった。正月には――二月には――と**便りの空だのみ**も、この頃は頼みに持てなくなった。もう今年の春も四月に入っているのだった。

宮本武蔵（1935年–1939年、朝日新聞連載、吉川英治）

What does 便りの空だのみ mean （空 pronounced as そら in audiobook)? Is it a fixed expression?

Reference: [aozora.gr.jp/cards/001562/files/52396_49781.html](http://aozora.gr.jp/cards/001562/files/52396_49781.html)

Comment: It's 便りの空だのみ not 便りの空

Comment: 「空頼み」って言葉があるみたいです　https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%A9%BA%E9%A0%BC%E3%81%BF-467501

Comment: ピンときました！ありがとう、 chocoさん

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be parsed as:

> 「[便]{たよ}り + の + [空]{そら}だのみ」

The "key" element here is 「空」, which ***does not*** mean "sky".  It means "empty", "vain", etc.

Thus, 「空だのみ」 means "hope against hope".  「たのみ」＝「頼み」.  「だ」 is a rendaku.

「便り」 means "correspondence", "letter", "news", etc.

All in all, you should have something like:

> "indulging in vain hope for a letter"
>
> "hope against hope for some news"

The 「空」 part could be read 「から」 as well.  Not sure which one was the author's intended reading.